# is it possible to create a date range in ruby from negative infinity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm struggling to define a date range in Ruby (2.6.3) that represents the range of dates up to a given date (in my examples it is Date.today):

`BigDecimal("Infinity")...Date.today`

> *** ArgumentError Exception: bad value for range

`nil...Date.today`

> *** ArgumentError Exception: bad value for range

`Date::Infinity.new...Date.today`

> *** ArgumentError Exception: bad value for range

`(Date.today...-Date::Infinity.new)`

> Fri, 31 May 2019...#

this one doesn't break, but also doesn't appear to give me a meaningful date range:

`(Date.today...-Date::Infinity.new).include? Date.yesterday`

> false

Comment: `(Date.today..-Date::Infinity.new).to_a` is just an empty array.

Comment: What's the use case for this? the range you want is the same as "any date less than today", what do you want to do what that range? It sounds too complicated and maybe there are better options for whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need infinity? How far back in time do you really need to go? Can't you just do something like this:

```
[*100.year.ago.to_date...Date.today]
```

Comment: that's probably what I'm going to end up doing -- my application also needs to be able to distinguish between ranges that start at -infinity vs ones that start at a defined time, and I'd prefer not to have the dependency on the arbitrary 100 year value. It's not the worst thing, but I was hoping Ruby's infinite range support would make it possible

Comment: I get it, but you could do something somewhat arbitrary that still covers your use case.  It might also be helpful if you provide code example of your implementation or spec.

Comment: I think this is in fact better than negative infinity because I don't think you will usually want dates from the time of the dinosaurs. This will act as a check to ensure that someone is not trying to enter garbage values. But if your question was merely hypothetical, then I am not sure :)

Comment: This answer was the most useful - my insistence on the infinite range was because it seems like it should be possible - it can be done with numbers, why not dates - and because it would have simplified my work. I needed to create a set of date ranges and then "invert" that set elsewhere (create a set of ranges representing the times not covered by the original ranges). A range that starts at 100 years ago inverts to a range from minus infinity to 100 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the best solution, but it can be helpful:

```
(-Float::INFINITY...Date.today.to_time.to_i).include? Date.yesterday.to_time.to_i
 => true
```

Answer (score 2):

As of ruby 2.7, this is no longer an issue, infinite ranges are handled gracefully:

```
(..Date.today).cover?(100.years.ago)
=> true
(nil..Date.today).cover?(100.years.ago)
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in passing time ranges to ActiveRecord because you're using Ruby on Rails, `Time.new(Float::MAX)` and `Time.new(-Float::MAX)` are useful.

Here's an example:

```
def before(time)
  Time.new(-Float::MAX)..time
end

def after(time)
  time..Time.new(Float::MAX)
end

user.comments.where(created_at: before(user.subscribed_at))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, [Ruby 2.6.x added](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12912) (see comments) endless ranges, `..Date.today` gives `.cover?(other_date) == true` for all Dates before today.

Comment: I'm looking with ruby 2.6.6 and still get the same errors: `(..Date.today).cover?(100.years.ago)` gives me `syntax error, unexpected ..` and `(nil..Date.today).cover?(100.years.ago)` gives me `bad value for range`. However, support is there in ruby 2.7.3.